# How to recover/copy data off disks that were once part of a RAID1 (LVM on MD) in a 2-disk NAS?

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, raid, mdadm

I have got a 2-disk NAS configured by the builtin software to be a RAID1 array. On this were two volumes (LVM on MD) with data. Now I replaced the two disks and wish to copy over the old data.

I have the two disks connected to a Linux PC via USB, now I want to mount the volumes.  This is how it looks like:

```
# lsblk | tail -11
sdp                              8:240  0   3.7T  0 disk  
├─sdp1                           8:241  0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdp2                           8:242  0   1.9G  0 part  
└─sdp3                           8:243  0   3.7T  0 part  
sdq                             65:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdq1                          65:1    0   1.9G  0 part  
├─sdq2                          65:2    0   1.9G  0 part  
└─sdq3                          65:3    0 927.7G  0 part  
  └─md124                        9:124  0 927.6G  0 raid1 
    ├─vg_a8765432-vg_info_area 254:9    0   100M  0 lvm   
    └─vg_a8765432-lv_37654321  254:10   0 927.5G  0 lvm
```

Since I have not enough experience with MD and LVM would someone please tell me **how to mount the ext4 partitions inside MD+LVM in order to recover the files**?

There is no defect or data inconsistency in/on the old drives (no repair necessary).  They will later be reformatted and reused in a different context.  Nonetheless if I could mount them `ro` now I would prefer that.

UPDATE: The data from `sdq3` has been recovered (thanks @hauke-laging), so now `sdp3` (another "linux_raid_member") is the remaining of the two data partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir --mode=000 /mnt/old_volume
mount -o ro /dev/vg_a8765432/lv_37654321 /mnt/old_volume
ls -l /mnt/old_volume
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed one of those elusive data partitions!  Now, where is the other one hidden? Any ideas?

Comment: PS: It did work on the other disk, too, after swapping the USB enclosures. Apparently the Toshiba DWC130 enclosure "hides/invalidates" the MD and/or LVM data (maybe by re-mapping the sector/cluster size?).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need raparation for now ... just mount your old LVM media use cp or rsync to copy you data ... this is the "simple" method, and secondary yes it is a good idea to mount on ReadOnly during copy operation.

Comment: If I knew how to mount the partitions I would have done it already. So: How? Please list the commands, then it's an answer.

Comment: only you can say that, you only have access to your machine only you can list their names from pvs vgs & lvs to list the physical volumes, volumes group & logical volumes.   then mount the LVM as usual mount command  `cat /etc/fstab` if you need examples. typical `mount -o ro /dev/mapper/vgname/lvname /someemptydirecroty`  else edit your first post with real question within all needed informations :)

Comment: I edited the question.  So, I need commands like `mdadm`, possibly `mdcreate`, then `pvscan`, `lvscan` and possibly more to create some `/dev/mapper/yippee_almost_done1` with `ext4`. The rest I can do!